# Can you Simplify This Complex Expression?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  Does the expression $(a+i b)^{1/3} + (a-i b)^{1/3}$ simplify to a real valued expression defined solely in terms $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+bi = z$ and assume that $|z| = 1$. Then $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. Then the sum is equal to $\cos \theta/3+i \sin \theta/3+ \cos \theta/3-i \sin \theta/3 = 2 \cos \theta/3$ which is real.

Comment: That's only on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. How about in general?

Comment: The assumption of unit modulus is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, we can add an $r^(1/3)$ in from where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and your $\theta = \mathrm{arctan}(b/a)$.

Comment: I just assumed $|z| = 1$ just to make things a bit simpler. Besides, we can always scale things.

Comment: Granted. But that reduces the generality of your argument, leading to the objection raised.  Since you can "rescale" the result, you need to show that in some way.  (Part of the point in writing a "good" mathematical proof or argument is to head off as many legitimate objections as possible -- preferably, _all_ of them.)

Answer (score 0):

We can also look at this geometrically, knowing (from DeMoivre) how the roots of a complex number are arranged on the complex plane.  The number $ \ z = a + bi \ $ has its three cube roots arranged 120º apart on a circle with a radius given by the cube root of the modulus of $ \ z \ $  [marked in blue].  The complex conjugate $ \ \overline{z} \ $ has its three cube-roots [marked in red] also spaced 120º apart on this same circle (since it has the same modulus as $ \ z \ $ , its cube-roots must have the same moduli as the cube-roots of $ \ z \ $ ) .

Since $ \ \overline{z} \ $ has an argument which is the negative of that of $ \ z \ $ , its cube-roots will have arguments which are the negative of those for the cube-roots of $ \ z \ $ .  So the cube-roots of $ \ \overline{z} \ $ are the complex conjugates of those of $ \ z \ $ . The sum of each cube-root and its corresponding conjugate is then a real number.

This graph is not offered as a "proof-by-picture" , but simply to illustrate the situation.

[image]